# Use of UISearchBar with NSAttributedStrings for Highlith the search text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Hi Can any one help me how i can use NSAttributedStrings with UISearchBar. actually i want to search text from array or database and then want to highlight the matching keyword, How i can highlight the matching keyword? Please Help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Custom Cell with [**OHAttributedLabel**](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) in it for display of Highlighted search text according to result

Comment: thanks for your response i m using Custom Cell but i m confuse that how i can use OHAttributedLabel from this code into my code. i just want to highlight the text means to change the color of the matching text. my code in cellforRowAtIndexPath is     `myCustomCell *Customcell = (myCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customIdentifier];
    if (Customcell == nil) {
        Customcell = [[[myCustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:customIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
Customcell.charName.text = [copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: add OHAttributedLabel  in customcell to display text in tableview and that label will be used for changing color of text according to your requirement

Comment: i have added OHAttributedLabel in my custom cell but there is no affect the cell is displaying is same, in my custom class i have also added fillLabel1() method to change the color but no change? sorry for foolish question i m new so that's why i m asking such a question?

Comment: Check demo and its use throughly. Now Find nsrange of search text in OHAttributedLabel's text and use that nsrange to differnt color u want

Comment: i have found the nsrange f searchtext and given to OHAttributed Label's text and the color is also working but now the question is that look to my code `[now setTextColor:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,[searchKeyword length])];`  so it gives red color from the 0 index of the cell? i want to highlight the searchKeyword with the correct index. so how i can find the location of searchKeyword in a sentence e.g "i m happy" so if i search for m so just m should be display in red color while here it start from the start

Comment: NSRange searchrange = [(OHAttributed Label's text)  
 rangeOfString :searchKeyword]; [now setTextColor:[UIColor redColor] range:searchranget];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13101/discussion-between-safecase-and-shaheen-rehman)